# Should I say "I'm going to see" or "I'm going to"?

Tags: ellipsis, future-tense, responses

In the following situation:

> --Have you gone to see the doctor?
> --No, but_______.

Should I say "I'm going to see" or "I'm going to"?

I feel like the former one makes more sense, because it at least has the actual verb "see," whereas the latter one is only left with a model verb "be going to," which by itself doesn't mean anything but a future tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the opposite is true.

The correct version is "No but I'm going to". It doesn't need to mean anything but a future tense, since it is referring back to what the other person said.

"No but I'm going to see" would not make sense here. You could only use that in the sense of "wait and see":

> "Have you decided if you're going to the doctor yet?"
>
> "No, I'm going to see if it gets better by itself."

Comment: Or if you added "I'm going to see **him/her tomorrow**."